# Intuition why NP $\subsetneq$ EXPTIME would hold?

Tags: complexity-theory

We know that **P** $\subsetneq$ **EXPTIME**, and that **P** $\subseteq$ **NP** $\subseteq$ **EXPTIME**.

I hear alot about the **P = NP** question and why it would intuitively be weird if it holds true, but I don't hear about the intuition behind why people think that **NP** $\subsetneq$ **EXPTIME**.

Are there intuitive reasons to assume that **NP = EXPTIME** or not? Why would we think one way or the other?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, clearly you haven't read one of these questions.

Comment: I think the answer to the old question also fits this question.

Comment: If you disagree, you can vote to reopen your question.